# The type initializer for 'Homepage.Controllers.AppFlowMetadata' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-api

This is weird.

This is related to the article "Using OAuth 2.0 with Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)": https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

Disregard the entire code, no need, the question is this - there is a method:

```
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]
            },
            Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
            DataStore = new FileDataStore(folder)
            //DataStore = new FileDataStore("Google.Auth.Store")
        });
```

If I use **DataStore = new FileDataStore(folder)** everything works,

however, according to the documentation, I can just use

**DataStore = new FileDataStore("Google.Auth.Store")**

So, according to this article (http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/) we should have a new folder called **Google.Auth.Store** created here with all the JSON token files in it:

**%AppData%\Roaming\Google.Auth.Store\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user**

**Never happens!**

Instead I get a blank page with a single error message:

> Index is not loading, try again later The type initializer for
>   'Homepage.Controllers.AppFlowMetadata' threw an exception.

Why is this happening? according to the documentation this is exactly how it should be.

Comment: IIS probably doesn't have permissions to write to %AppData% It doesn't matter where you store it.   folder is file.

Comment: Thanks, that could be the reason. I tried to set IIS site Pool Identity to Local System, that should have access to everything, but it's not working either. weird.